# Dell xps 13 ubuntu 20 touchpad not moving after login

Tags: touchpad

At some point this started and is super annoying - after login the touchpad stops moving the pointer, but clicking still has an effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long trial and error:

```
xinput set-prop 12 316 0
```

where `12` is the device id I got from `xinput list`, and `316` is a stupid attribute which is called `Synaptics Off (316):`. For me it was set to `1` for some reason, so I set it to `0` using the above command.